# Query across tables with Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

I have two tables, `users` and `alternative_users` that are exactly the same besides a few MySQL performances tweaks.

**I'd like to be able to query the second table from the first model to be able to run tests without having to change my entire codebase.**

This would mean able to have this query hit the `alternative_users` table but still return `User` objects. To sum it up:

```
users = User.select(fields).where(conditions).limit(10) # hits alternative_users

# or

users = AlternativeUser.select(fields).where(conditions).limit(10) # returns User object
```

---

Note that `find_by_sql` has this ability:

```
users = User.find_by_sql("select * from alternative_users")`
```

... and it works fine, but I want to avoid rewriting code and my codebase is filled with arel keywords (`where`, `limit`...) and `find_by_sql` just returns an array so I can't chain.

Also note that I want this behavior only for a few queries, not the entire app. Because of this I can't use `table_name`.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh No, just for a few given queries for a performance test. If I wanted to change everywhere I could use `table_name`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh :) I'll update the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just change individual Relation queries, there's a method for that: [`from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from) will override the FROM clause to point to whatever you like.

```
User.select(:name).from("alternative_users").to_a
# SELECT name FROM alternative_users;
```

---

If you want to access both tables from throughout your application, then I'd suggest doing it with subclasses:

Rename `User` to `AbstractUser`, and add:

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

Then create empty subclasses:

```
class User < AbstractUser
end

class AlternativeUser < AbstractUser
end
```

That gives you two very similar model classes (same methods etc), but keeps them separate so you know which one you're asking for (and which one an association is linked to, for example).

Comment: @JagdeepSingh "Rename User to AbstractUser" saves you from redefining things. I've found having a subclass of a non-abstract class that's using a different table can get messy & confusing.

Comment: Thank, this seems like very good ideas! I'm running into an issue that I'll need to figure out with fields being prefixed `select users.id from alternative_users` (the query is of course way more complex, but it's to give the general idea :) ). I'll debug this and come back to this post.

Comment: You can solve that by aliasing it back to `users`: `.from("alternative_users", :users)` should do it